# Stack trace function in C

Tags: c, recursion, stack-trace, printstacktrace

Im trying to write a function in C that identifies the top of the stack and determines the first frame pointer. Then I have a different function that recursively prints the current stack frame and calls itself with the next stack frame's pointer. Any tips on how to do this and get started?

```
    void stackTrace(int prms, int localVars){

    }

    void nextTrace(unsigned int *framePointer, int prms, int localVars){

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/master/docs/getting_started_with_breakpad.md https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp

Answer (score 0):

```
int backtrace(void **buffer, int size) {
    extern uint64_t *__libc_stack_end;
    uint64_t **p, *bp, *frame;
    asm ("mov %%rbp, %0;" : "=r" (bp));
    p = (uint64_t**) bp;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        frame = p[0];
        if (frame < bp || frame > __libc_stack_end) {
            return i;
        }
        buffer[i++] = p[1];
        p = (uint64_t**) frame;
    }
    return i;
}
```

That's how I did it, because GNU `backtrace` did not work with TinyC. I think my function wotks witm gcc/clang as well. The trick here is to start from the address stored in RBP (on x86_64) and walk until `__libc_stack_end` which is a builtin variable.